# Not able to login to newly created account

Tags: permissions, password, users, login-screen

I am a new linux user/administrator and I just set up ubuntu 18.04. I am having difficulty creating a viable user/nonadministrator account.

I have done this with the terminal with user (antonk):

```
adduser antonk
```

That works and I can log in with the terminal.  However, I can't login from the opening screen. Every time I enter the password the screen turns black and sends me back to the login screen.  I think one of the scripts that is run automatically is failing and it is not an authentication issue.

I also tried creating a user using the GUI and that works about the same.  This time I left the password to be entered by user the first time.  When I tried to login this time, I was prompted for a new password. Once I entered this the same error occurred.  I just installed 18.04, just downloaded it, and I have not seen any problems with the install.  When I exit, some of the text that flashes on the screen says "grub ... fail" but I can't read the message.

The directory names are correct.
output of `sudo grep antonk /etc/passwd`:

```
antonk:x:1001:1001:AntonK,,,:/home/antonk:/bin/bash
output of ls -d /home/antonk is:
drwxr-xr-x 14 antonk antonk 4096 Mar 24 12:53 /home/antonk
```

Looks like the directory name and permissions are correct.

The desktop environment in Gnome, and I am using an NVidia graphics card.  I never updated the driver for that at all.  Also as administrator, I am able to log-in just fine.  I get to the desktop after entering my password. but I can't using a newly created account.

Any guidance would help.

Comment: What Desktop Environment are you using?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#download.  I downloaded 18.04 Desktop so I think that is the environment.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are logging in with the terminal?

Comment: I open a terminal window and enter su antonk, type in password and it works.  I can type whoami and I get antonk, groups yields antonk, and I can create directories  and files in home.  As antonk, I cannot create directories in the administrator account.

Comment: From the login screen press `CTRL + ALT + F3` this will take you into the terminal window, try there.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help, Robby1212.  I got this to work.  I think the issue was the graphics driver and the NVidia card.  By installing the NVidia graphics driver, I was able to login with the other user account.  Below is the output of nvidia-smi.  I think some of this was not working with the preinstalled Ubuntu graphics drivers, and hence the login problem into Gnome. To install, I followed this:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/.
antona@antona-MS-7A20:~$ nvidia-smi

Wed Mar 25 10:54:41 2020

Comment: Ah good old Nvidia, always causing problems!